# Reading stdout and stderr as it Arrives Using Asyncio

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I have code that schedules two tasks (both simple python scripts) and runs them. However, I want to read the stdout/stderr as they are written via the task. Currently, my code is only returning them after the subprocess finishes. Note, I am using Python 3.9.13.

Below are the two simple scripts which just print to stdout as well as the `main.py` which runs the async subprocesses.

hello_europe.py

```
import time

print("Hello Europe!!")
print("I am going to sleep for 5 seconds...")
time.sleep(5)
print("done sleeping! waking up now! :)")
```

hello_usa.py

```
print("Hello USA!!")
```

main.py

```
import asyncio
import sys

if sys.platform == "win32":
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy())

async def _watch(stream, prefix="") -> None:
    async for line in stream:
        print(prefix, line.decode().rstrip())

async def _run_cmd(cmd) -> None:
    # Create subprocess
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        cmd, stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )

    # I assume this is where something is going wrong
    await _watch(proc.stdout, "stdout:")
    await _watch(proc.stderr, "stderr:")

    # This will wait until subprocess finishes! We do not want that!
    # stdout, stderr = await proc.communicate()
    # if stdout:
    #     print(f"stdout:\n{stdout.decode()}")
    # if stderr:
    #     print(f"stderr\n{stderr.decode()}")

def get_tasks() -> list[str]:
    europe_tasks: list[str] = [
        "python hello_europe.py"
    ]

    usa_tasks: list[str] = [
        "python hello_usa.py"
    ]
    return usa_tasks + europe_tasks

async def _run_all() -> None:
    tasks: list[str] = get_tasks()

    hello_tasks: list[asyncio.Task] = [
        asyncio.create_task(_run_cmd(i))
        for i in tasks
    ]
    await asyncio.wait(hello_tasks)

def main() -> None:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(_run_all())
    loop.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg 3.9.13

Comment: This is caused by the application you are launching, not the application doing the reading.  Most applications use buffered output, so nothing gets written to file until an output buffer is full.  If you are launching Python apps, you can try using `python -u`, which disables buffering.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for sharing. Is there a way to determine how large the output buffer will be before it is flushed to stdout/stderr or potentially a flat file?

Comment: No, it varies by operating system, and sometimes by applilcation.